# Dataset details in a SAS library

Tags: sas

Can someone please help. I would like to create a table showing all datasets created by me in a particular library, the sizes and dates of creation/modification.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The view `sashelp.vtable` or the dictionary table `dictionary.tables` both provide this information in table form, as does `proc datasets`.